# Chrome and Firefox prevent downloading a dynamically created zip file saying it is an unusual download and could be harmful

Tags: php, google-chrome, security, firefox, zip

Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox classify my zip file as potentially harmful.

[This is what users see when downloading the zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb07q.jpg)

I wrote some peace of code (PHP, Codeigniter) which creates a zip file dynamically and let's the user download it immediately. This peace of code is only reachable after an user login. On localhost everything works fine but on production Google Chrome and Mozilla firefox classify the zip file as potentially harmful.

The production is HTTPS encrypted with a domain validated certificate by RapidSSL.

I did some research and found:

- Since zip is a binary file and the website itself is not known enough, the download is generally classified as untrustworthy.
- If it were a static file accessible via a public URL, Google would inspect it sooner or later and then classify it as safe. Since these are dynamically created ZIP files that can only be accessed in the login area, this option is no longer available.
- It could be that the SSL certificate is not secure enough because it is only domain validated. Before I buy a more expensive one here, I wanted to hear your opinion about this possible solution. Will a better certificate ensure that the Zip files are considered safe?
- I don't have my software in the Google Search Console. Could that do anything?
- During my research I came across the http header "Content Security Policy". Would setting this header be the solution?

I tried both codeigniter zip library and PHP's ZipArchive. Both solutions had the same problem. The headers I set for downloading after creating the zip file with PHP's ZipArchive are the following:

```
//Set the Content-Type, Content-Disposition and Content-Length headers.
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_name");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_path_and_filename));

//Read the file data and exit the script.
readfile($zip_path_and_filename);
exit;
```

I expected that the zip file will be downloaded without classifying it as potentially harmful. In fact Microsoft Edge does not complain anything.